# IDE that tracks changes in the scrollbar

Tags: text-editor, ide, visual-studio

I use Visual Studio 2013 for developing in C# and I like the change tracking in the scrollbar and on the left side.

> [image]
>
> [Color Indicator for Code Changes in Visual Studio 2010](https://abhijitjana.net/2010/09/14/color-indicator-for-code-changes-track-changes-in-visual-studio-2010/)

I want to use this feature when I develop in other languages, like PHP or Java.

Is there an extension for Eclipse, Brackets, Visual Studio Code, or any other text editor to do this?

Comment: Please restrict this question to only Eclipse or Brackets, or another clearly stated IDE, thanks! You can post a new question for each IDE, if you want.

Comment: Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA do that for Java.

Comment: CudaText editor has this "line states" feature (on the left).